# PKCS#11 C_getfunctionlist in a dll

Tags: pkcs#11

I'm trying to write a dll which will eventually connect to a virtual token. I tried to make an exportable C_getfunctionlist function which will contain pointer adressess to functions suported by PCKS#11 standard but i can't figure out why i can't access those functions in the program that uses the dll. I tried to load just the C_Initializefunction.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
CK_RV C_GetFunctionList(CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR_PTR ppFunctionList) {
    CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR function_list;
    function_list=new CK_FUNCTION_LIST;
    function_list->C_Initialize=&C_Initialize;
    ppFunctionList=&function_list;
return CKR_OK;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a pkcs#11 implementation's functions in your code you have to load the dll which implements the standard and then use functions provided by the dll. Here comes the code I use on Linux system. I hope it helps.

```
static char const * PKCS11_SO_NAME = "/usr/lib/pkcs11/PKCS11_API.so";

static void * pkcs11_so;
//list of all pkcs#11 functions
static CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR pkcs11;

CK_RV load_pkcs11() {
  CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
  CK_RV (*C_GetFunctionList) (CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR_PTR) = 0;

  pkcs11_so = dlopen(PKCS11_SO_NAME, RTLD_NOW);
  if (!pkcs11_so) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error loading pkcs#11 so: %s\n", dlerror());
    return CKR_GENERAL_ERROR;
  }

  rv = load_symbol((void **)&C_GetFunctionList, "C_GetFunctionList");
  if (CKR_OK != rv) {
    return rv;
  }

  rv = C_GetFunctionList(&pkcs11);
  if (CKR_OK != rv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "C_GetFunctionList call failed: 0x%.8lX", rv);
    return rv;
  }

  return CKR_OK;
}
```