# Linking error for a C application using PKCS#11 API

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11, hsm, opensc

I am trying to compile an example basic code that performs PKCS#11 initialization only but get following error;

```
gcc pkcs11_example1.c -o pk -L /usr/lib64/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so 
/tmp/cc8Dl0HE.o: In function `initialize':
pkcs11_example1.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `C_GetFunctionList'
pkcs11_example1.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `assert'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the rpm command shows following so paths

```
rpm -ql opensc
/usr/lib64/libopensc.so.3
/usr/lib64/libopensc.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib64/libsmm-local.so.3
/usr/lib64/libsmm-local.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
/usr/lib64/pkcs11
/usr/lib64/pkcs11-spy.so
/usr/lib64/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so
/usr/lib64/pkcs11/pkcs11-spy.so
```

my code is pasted below

```
CK_RV  
initialize()
{
    CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR pFunctionList;
    CK_C_Initialize pC_Initialize; 
    CK_RV rv;

  /* It’s OK to call C_GetFunctionList before calling
     * C_Initialize */
    rv = C_GetFunctionList(&pFunctionList);
    assert(rv == CKR_OK);
    pC_Initialize = pFunctionList -> C_Initialize; 

    /* Call the C_Initialize function in the library */
    rv = (*pC_Initialize)(NULL_PTR);
    return rv;

}

int    
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rv = initialize();
}
```

but still getting the error

```
undefined reference to `C_GetFunctionList'
```

Kindly guide how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error stems from the fact that your program has the right headers (functions definitions), but not the implementation of said functions. 
Before you start to use the PKCS#11 functions implemented in your DLL (opensc-pkcs11.so, in your case), you actually have to load it.

I'm no pro on DLL loading in unix systems, but i think [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) should do the trick.

On a side note, i'd strongly advise you to always call C_Finalize(...) after a call to C_Initialize.

Good luck !

Comment: for others clarification, first we need to open dynamic lib with **dlopen** get its symbol with **dlsym** and use **pC_GetFunctionList** to get pointer to all pkcs#11 functions supported by so. These links helped me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615001/pkcs11-c-getfunctionlist-in-a-dll), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133704/unable-to-compile-a-c-application-that-reads-smartcard) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764447/linking-error-with-opensc-pkcs). Thank you for the help every one.

Answer (score 0):

What include files are you using?

```
#include <assert.h>
```

probally also need

```
#include <pkcs11.h>
```

In addition, -L is to specify  a path to seatch for a library. -l specifies the library.

so you would need -L/usr/lib64/ -lpkcs11

Comment: I have already included `#include ''pkcs11.h"` and tried -l or -L before but not successful.  `#include <assert.h>` was missing so I added it but it has nothing to do with the main problem of linking with pkcs11 problem, so still a moot point

Comment: so when you use something like 'gcc  pkcs11_example1.c  -o  pk  -L/usr/lib64/pkcs11 -lopensc-pkcs11' what is the error ?

Comment: Its not successful when i compile using this command  `gcc -L/usr/lib64/ -lopensc-pkcs11 pkcs11_example1.c -o pk` the output is `/bin/ld: cannot find -lopensc-pkcs11`   I used `/usr/lib64` instead of `/usr/lib64/pkcs11` because the later one was having symbolic link.

Comment: whats /usr/lib64/pkcs11 a symlink to?

Comment: symlink to;  `opensc-pkcs11.so -> ../opensc-pkcs11.so`

Comment: and is /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so a symlink as well?

Comment: `/usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so` is not a symlink